# Parity keystore wallet recovery

Tags: recovery, parity-wallet

So, I created a new wallet using parity and should have mistyped the password, I am not able to access the wallet at the moment.

Is there a tool like https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover for brute forcing a wallet created by Parity?

Comment: Have you kept the memo phrases somewhere? You can recover the account out of it.

Comment: Have you tried using pyethrecover yet? Keys are in a similar format like geth keys.

Answer (score 0):

No, the pyethrecover repo isn't working properly, you have to use hashcat https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat and btcrecover https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover.

If you don't know the commands and way to brute force visit my profile.

We don't demand of private key file or any data, just share hash we will crack it and hand over password.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post more information about how people can run those tools. Because if you run it for them, how can they trust that you won't steal from them?

Comment: We don't demand of private key file or any data just share hash we will crack it and hand over password

Comment: How do people get the hash? What type of hash is it?

Comment: You can use ethereum2john.py

Comment: Or bitcoin2john.py to get hash